# Weird clipboard issue with vim-gnome and gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, clipboard

## Problem

In `gnome-terminal` I run `vim-gnome`. I can copy anything from vim and I can paste it successfully anywhere, but as soon as I paste it in the gnome-terminal the clipboard is somehow flushed. Even if I try again to paste in any other app (e.g. browser) it will paste nothing.

## System configuration

- elementary os freya (ubuntu based)
- vim-gnome with +clipboard, +xterm_clipboard support
- gnome-terminal (default on ubuntu)
- autokey scripts to change systemwide (except gnome-terminal) paste to super+v, and in gsettings of gnome-terminal using super+v (instead of shift+control+f)

  - do not think is important but sharing anyway

## Vim configuration

```
" actually the following line was copied from vim
" and pasted in the browser
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

## Additional info

- restoring the paste shortcut in gsettings of gnome-terminal tp +v still results to the same problem
- copying e.g from browser and pasting to gnome-terminal works just fine

Comment: Check if the problem persists if you use an external program to manage your clipboard such as `parcellite`.